# Proguard obfuscate only /WEB-INF/classes/**/*.class files in my war

Tags: java, war, proguard

I want to obfuscate only the server-side code (webapp.war:/WEB-INF/classes/**).

How can I do this using proguard maven plugin ?

Comment: You use the [`<outFilter>` option](http://wvengen.github.io/proguard-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ProGuard offers options of [filters](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#filters) for many different aspects of the configuration.

A filter is a list of comma-separated names that can contain wildcards.
Only names that match an item on the list pass the filter.

You can use `<outFilter>` to apply ProGuard to output jar.
outFilter is optional parameter to apply ProGuard classpathentry filters to output jar.

In your case I guess below filter should work. Off course you can add additional comma separated filters.(ignore the space in between forward splash and asterik mark)

```
<outFilter>**/WEB-INF/classes/ **.class</outFilter>
```